# How to warmup cache as :webserver_user using capifony?

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano, file-permissions, capifony

When I deploy my Symfony2 application I encounter an obstacle: I have to connect to a server as user `foo` but apache runs as user `www-data`. 
I want to use cache warmup but then `app/cache/prod` is created by user `foo` not by `www-data` which can be later used by apache.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
su www-data <my command here>
```

Will switch you to the www-data user to run the command.

Better yet:

```
chmod -R www-data app/cache/prod
```

To change the ownership

Maybe even better

```
chown -R o+rw app/cache/prod
```

This will allow "o"thers read and write the cache.

You could even set the `+S` bit on the app/cache, so that files created in there get automatic clean permissions.

Comment: in general what you suggest is good, but none of the above applies to this server, since it's a shared hosting.

Comment: On shared hosting, Capistrano is unlikely to work well for you. I'd say you ought to be able to chmod your cache files to `o+rw`  (i.e allow others to read and write your files), but assuming that all other websites on the host run as `www-data`, any of them can steal your database, read your cache, and/or other things you would prefer not to deal with. Shared hosting is a terrible environment for this stuff.

Comment: I know that, but since it's an in-university shared hosting I started negotiating with the admin. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Good luck, renczus. It sounds like most of your problems are related to the restricted university environment and not really like someone from outside can help you. I'd appreciate an *Accept* if you deem my advice to have been useful, would it not have been for your extenuating circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

As of Capifony 2.1.x new permission functions have been adedded.

Please have a look at the documentation chapter [Automatically set proper permissions](http://capifony.org/cookbook/set-permissions.html).

```
set :use_set_permissions, true    # enables setting the permissions
set :writable_dirs,       ["app/cache", "app/logs"]
set :webserver_user,      "www-data"
set :permission_method,   :acl    # (:acl|:chmod|:chown)
```